# Django ImportError: no module named 'shop'

Tags: python, django

I tried searching for answers to this problem but, at least with my eyeballs, I did not find the same problem anywhere else.

I started doing a django project from the book "Django by example'. I've been using a virtual environment. Following the book, I downloaded Django 1.8.6.

I added the app 'shop' into the list of apps in the settings file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
)
```

I created the models according to the book.

Then I tried "makingmigrations" but it gives me ImportError. Like this:

```
(myenv) C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop>python manage.py runserver --traceback
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x0000000003EEEB70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autorel
oad.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\commands\runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autorel
oad.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py"
, line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autorel
oad.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py",
 line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry
.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Subject\djangoshop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.p
y", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'shop'
```

There is a blank `__init__.py` file in the app shop/.

This picture should show some of the tree. I took it from PyCharm. (I tried the tree command in the command prompt but it was terribly long.)
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r09rC.png)

I think I followed the directory structure given by the book:

```
django-admin startproject myshop
cd myshop/
django-admin startapp shop
```

I was not able to create the virtual environment the way the book instructs, so I created it following this tutorial http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/

Comment: you don't add the app created like that.
Write `shop.apps.shopConfig`.

Comment: Do you mean changing the settings.py? 'shop.apps.shopConfig' instead of 'shop' in the installed apps? I tried that and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: yes, i meant that.
Your app (eg-shops) should be connected to the class name of apps.py file.
Check the class name and write like this: `shops.apps.NameOfTheClassInAppsPyFile`

Comment: Your directory tree looks messed up. I would expect there to be a `myshop` directory that contained `manage.py`, a `myshop/myshop` directory that contained the `settings.py` and your `myshop/shop` app directory containing your models and so on. Since it's a new project, I would try deleting in, then running the startproject and startapp commands again.

Comment: The book uses `shop`, so you shouldn't need to switch to an app config to get it to work.

Comment: @Alasdair tell me if I'm wrong but isn't that the directory tree that the book  says. (I added what the book instructs into the question area.)

Comment: The commands in the book are pretty standard. Your screenshot looks wrong because you don't appear to have the inner `myshop/myshop` directory that contains the settings, wsgi and URLs files. It's tricky to debut this remotely, so as I said before, I recommend deleting and trying again.

Comment: Ok now I got it working. It seems that Alasdair was right. Maybe I used the command 'django-admin startproject myshop .' (The dot in the end changes the structure. Some other tutorials say how important the dot is.). And then I created the app in the wrong directory where the settings file is. Thanks a lot for your help Alasdair!

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. It's better to add your solution as an answer, rather than including it in your question. That way you can accept your answer, to show that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I created the app in the wrong folder. Come to think of it, I think I used this command:

```
django-admin startproject myshop .
```

With the dot in the end, as some tutorials recommend. So that messed up the structure so it became incompatible with the book's instructions.

So, as Alasdair recommended, I started the project again from the beginning, and the problem disappeared.